# How to add number to a date column with some predifined conditions in SQL?

Tags: sql

In the below sql code i am trying to compare two column in which if column B is empty or zero then add the date column to column A else add the date column to column B. However i am not getting result as i am getting the following error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function day(real) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 107
```

Below is the sql code:

```
select distinct 
  (concat(concat(documentno,'_'),itemno)) inv_num
, (case when dis_day2 =0 
     then baselinedate +day(dis_day1) 
     else baselinedate +day(dis_day2) 
   end) z
, *
from close items
where doc_type='BB' 
  and clearingda<='2020-05-18' 
group by z 
limit 100
```

Comment: Which database management system are you working with? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? Vertica? Oracle? Teradata? IBM DB2? Working with dates and parts of dates differs considerably between DBMSs ... But, already now: You can't expect to try to extract a day out of a `real` type expecting some magic to miraculously convert the `real` to a date/time type and hope to get away with that ...

Comment: @marcothesane  i use  PostgreSQL

Comment: @marcothesane i am getting the same error

Comment: Can you run a `\d close` (as that seems to be the name of your table, and paste the result of that in your question?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code just does not make sense:

```
(case when dis_day2 = 0 then baselinedate +day(dis_day1) 
      else baselinedate +day(dis_day2) 
 end)
```

In databases that have a `day` function, it extracts the day-of-month field from a date or similar type.  But you are comparing the value to `0` and the error message suggests that it is a `real`.

I suspect you want:

```
baselinedate + (case when dis_day2 = 0 then dis_day_1 else dis_day2 end) * interval '1 day'
```

This adds the number of days to the baseline date.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using DATE_PART()

The DATE_PART() function extracts a subfield from a date or time value

For your case, please try date_part('day', source)

For example

```
 date_part('day', dis_day1)
```